# Must provide source or customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

getting an error with stripe in local testing transfer recipients. 
I check SQL lite browser  and the user has a stripe recipient ID

I tried clearing my entire database, creating a new listing and then placing an order and getting the same error. not sure of the cause of this error, and help would be great!

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError in OrdersController#create
```

Must provide source or customer.

```
begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => token
```

Comment: are you sure token is set to an actual value?

Answer (score 0):

This was a turbo-links issue. I fixed the issue by inputting the following code

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<%= link_to 'New Listing', new_listing_path, class: "btn btn-link", data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
<% end %>
```